# Update user on the same page laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, updatemodel

I am new to the framework and I have a question.
I made a login authentication to access and when I go to my profile page I can view my data and change all on the same page.
I need to go get my ID to be able to do the update or not needed?
What do I need to do?
The way I'm doing okay? I only need to create a route::post?

**my profile page:**

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <h5>{{ Session::get('message') }}</h5>
    </div>
@endif

{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'backend/perfil', 'name' => 'updateProfile', 'role' => 'form'))!!}

<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Utilizador', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Utilizador']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        {!! Form::label('nascimento', 'Data de nascimento', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::date('nascimento', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-md']) !!}
        {{ $errors->first('nascimento', '<span class=error>:message</span>') }}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        {!! Form::label('sexo', 'Sexo', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::select('sexo', ['Masculino', 'Feminino'], null, ['class' => 'form-control input-md']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::text('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Email']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Password']) !!}
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        {!! Form::label('rpassword', 'Confirmar password', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::password('rpassword', ['class' => 'form-control input-md', 'placeholder' => 'Confirmar password']) !!}
    </div>
</div>                          
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        {!! Form::label('imagem', 'Imagem', ['class' => 'label_perfil']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-5">
        {!! Form::file('imagem', ['class' => 'input-file']) !!}
    </div>
</div>   
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 30px;">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
        {!! Form::submit('Enviar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>
</div> 
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**My controller:**

```
public function perfil() {
    return view('backend/perfil.index');        
}           

public function updateProfile() {

    $profileData = Input::except('_token');
    $validation = Validator::make($profileData, User::$profileData);
    if ($validation->passes()) {
        User::where('id', Input::get('id'))->update($profileData);
        return view('backend/perfil.index')->with('message', 'Updated Succesfully');
    } else {
        return view('backend/perfil.index')->with('message', $validation->messages());
    }
}
```

**My route:**

```
Route::get('backend/perfil','BackendControlador@perfil');
Route::post('backend/perfil', 'BackendControlador@updateProfile');
```

**My app User:**

```
public static $profileData = array(
        'email' =>  'required|email',
        'name' =>  'required',
        );
```

Comment: You need to create a route post/get which will call a controller's function and there you need to implement a model action. You wanted to know how ?

Comment: yes i want to learn if you can help me

Comment: Ok, Writing for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the Detailed one what you wanted to do.

**Step 1 :** Open the Form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'updateProfile', 'name' => 'updateProfile', 'role' => 'form'))!!}
```

Note : Your form method action is empty. You shall view your source to see it

**Step 2 :** Write a route

Route::post('updateProfile', 'homeController@updateProfile');

It will call the `homeController'`s  `updateProfile` function

**Step 3 :** Define the Controller, validate the input and make your action done via model

Here's the simple/sample function for you

```
public function updateProfile()
    {
        $profileData = Input::except('_token');
        $validation = Validator::make($profileData, User::$profileData);
        if ($validation->passes()) {
            User::where('id', Input::get('id'))->update($profileData);
            return view('profile')->with('message', 'Updated Succesfully');
        } else {
            return view('profile')->with('message', $validation->messages());
        }

    }
```

What it does is it will get all the inputs except `_token` and store it in `$profileData`, then it will make a validation that is defined inside `$profileData` inside the `User` Model

Here is the Validator, you shall modify it

```
public static $profileData = array(
        'email' =>  'required|email',
        'name' =>  'required',
        );
```

**Step 4 :** Return the Result

If the validation is passed, then it will update in the table to where the user whose id is passed i.e., `Input::get('id')` , and we will return the page with `return view('profile')->with('message', 'Updated Succesfully');`

I consider your page name as `profile.blade.php` and you shall change it according to your blade,

If the validation is failed, then we will return the page with error messages

`return view('profile')->with('message', $validation->messages());`

You should have this in your blade to display your error messages

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <h5>{{ Session::get('message') }}</h5>
    </div>
@endif
```

**Note :**

If you don't want to refresh the page, then you shall just do an Ajax call to pass the variables and show/hide the results that is return by the Controller

Hope this helps you

Comment: I'm trying so working.
For now I carry the button submit it does refresh the page but not updated.

Comment: Have you defined the route and controller ?

Comment: Ok, Could you have this line `return  Input::all();`  in your `updateProfile` function at first line ?

Comment: {"_token":"usjq1OauaJu7esjTelzfiE9D7VzuNSnTYx5NHO4d","name":"teste","email":""}

Comment: i am trying with only 2 input [ name and email]

Comment: That's ok, Inside your `perfil.index` you have this one ? `@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <h5>{{ Session::get('message') }}</h5>
    </div>
@endif` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94887/discussion-between-jose-cerejo-and-sulthan-allaudeen).